# Syntax to get the collection size in a linq query?

Tags: linq

I am trying to use the SKIP(N) function in a linq query. The problem is I need to know the collection size (Count()) inorder to calculate N.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this query below... How do I get the Collection Size inside the Skip part of the query below ?

```
var t = from row in db.table where <Clause>
        orderby <row> ascending 
        group row by <row> into A
        select A).OrderBy(x => x.Key).Skip(Math.Max(0, <Need to know collection size> - N ).ToDictionary(......
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you're trying to retrieve the last N items, why don't you just order it in the opposite direction?

Comment: Can you tell as the meaning of the `.Skip(Math.Max(0, <Need to know collection size> - N )` from the point of view of the business logic?

Comment: As Jon Skeet has said, order in the opposite direction and use `Take(N)` instead of `Skip(size-N)`. Btw, is this `Linq-To-Objects` or a database driven provider?